# JBoss 7.1.1 undeploy on restart

Tags: jboss7.x

For some reason our standalone JBoss 7.1.1 undeploys my war file on shutdown/restart.

Deployment happens with maven from a remote machine (jboss-as-maven-plugin).

Stopping happens with local cli 9999 shutdown command.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it inaccessible after you restart the server?

Comment: If you can post the related logs? That will help you get a faster response.

Comment: @james the deployment is missing and the site is inaccessible

Comment: I think we'll need to see the logs as @jBug suggests. This sounds like odd behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it why this happens. I did not only restart but also replace/update my config file. But in the updated file the deployment part is missing. And then it seams that jboss does not re-deploy the war file.

Kind of a problem that configuration and deployment information are in the same file, there is no separation of concerns here.